# Mysql query with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

Simply put : I have a table with

```
columns : col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
datas   : val1  2   toto   t   f    f    f
          val1  2   toto   t   t    f    f
          val1  2   toto   f   t    f    t
          val2  3   tata   t   f    f    t
          val5  4   tutu   f   t    f    f
```

i want a query to give me this : val1 2  toto t t f t (the condition is where col2 = 2) = > the first 3 lines in one line with t when t is found in any of the last 4 columns

Is there any way to achieve this in one query ?

Comment: What is the type of your true/false fields? As boolean is in fact stored as Tinyint(1) you could just use SELECT MAX(field_name). Or if you only want true if the values do not match then use SELECT IF(MAX(field_name) != MIN(field_name),true,false)

Comment: @Tarsis it's a varchar in the DB , represented as t or f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`True` and `false` are internally `1` and `0`. Therefore a simple

```
SELECT
  col1, col2, col3, max(col4), 
  max(col5), max(col6), max(col7), 
  sum(col6 + col7) as one_of_them_is_greater_0_meaning_true
from your_table
group by 
  col1, col2, col3
```

will do.

EDIT: Since you're storing varchars (bad idea), replace each true/false column with

```
CASE WHEN col = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END /*of course replacing column name appropriatelly*/
```

EDIT 2:

```
SELECT
  col1, col2, col3, max(CASE WHEN col4 = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
  max(CASE WHEN col5 = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), max(CASE WHEN col6 = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), max(CASE WHEN col7 = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
  sum(CASE WHEN col6 = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN col7 = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as one_of_them_is_greater_0_meaning_true
from Table1
where col2 = 2
group by 
  col1, col2, col3
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c1ea/2/0)</kbd>

1 is true, 0 is false. You can replace that again if you want to. And use alias names for columns of course. It's just a proof of concept.

Comment: @ancyPants hey, the type is not my own choice it was imposed on me.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. In the fact the difficulty is having multiple ids returning same line with the last four cols different. I wish i had enough reputation points to upload images, that would help better explain but i don't.

Comment: Images are a bad idea anyway. Best would be if you created a http://sqlfiddle.com and shared the link.

Comment: I don't see why my query would not yield the desired result. Maybe you try a little harder to explain it well?

Comment: i accepted the answer but still have one more question :/ can i still ask ?.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then you can use

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, 
  MAX(IF(field4 = 't',1,0)) as is_any_field4_true, 
  MAX(IF(field5 = 't',1,0)) as is_any_field5_true, 
  MAX(IF(field6 = 't',1,0)) as is_any_field6_true, 
  MAX(IF(field7 = 't',1,0)) as is_any_field7_true 
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3
```

Comment: Well the Syntax i postet still solves your Problem (and is much cleaner and more straight forward than the whole case when else construct). In your case you just sum up the "is_any_fieldX_true" values like that: IF(MAX(IF(field4 = 't',1,0))+MAX(IF(field5 = 't',1,0))+MAX(IF(field6 = 't',1,0))+MAX(IF(field7 = 't',1,0)) > 0,'t','f'). But its still a poor DB design and therefore a bad performing query.